# How to solve error exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError : 'java.lang.String javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(java.lang.String)'

Tags: java, eclipse, polymorphism

I need to run a program of SaloonMain using eclipse IDE. I imported the library javax.swin.JOptionPane and use the JOptionPane.showInputDialog() to insert data but it popped an error like this :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.String javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog(java.lang.String)'
at lab2.SaloonMain.main(SaloonMain.java:24)

This is my SaloonMain code :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SaloonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String num;
        String name;
        String m;
        String d;
        String r;
        String c;
        String w;
        String dy;
        String t;
        double pay = 0.0;
        
        Saloon[] saloonUser = new Saloon[5];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < saloonUser.length; i++) 
        {
            num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Customer's IC number :");
            name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Customer's Name :");
            m = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("A member? True | False :");
            boolean m1 = Boolean.parseBoolean(m);
            d = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Date (MM/DD/YYYY) :");
            
            String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose (1)Hair Treatment | (2)Body Treatment");
            int ans = Integer.parseInt(choice);
            
            boolean r1 = false;
            boolean c1 = false;
            boolean w1 = false;
            boolean dy1 = false;
            
            if(ans==1) 
            {
                r = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hair rebonding? (1)Yes | (2)No :");
                if(r=="1") 
                    r1 = true;
                
                c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hair cutting? (1)Yes | (2)No :");
                if(c=="1") 
                    c1 = true;
                
                w = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hair washing? (1)Yes | (2)No :");
                if(w=="1") 
                    w1 = true;
                
                dy = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hair dyeing? (1)Yes | (2)No :");
                if(dy=="1") 
                    dy1 = true;
                
                HairTreatment ht = new HairTreatment(num,name,m1,d,r1,c1,w1,dy1); 
                pay = pay + ht.computePayment();
            }           
            else 
            {
                
                t = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Treatment type? (1)Several parts | (2)Full parts :");
                
                if(t=="1") 
                    t = "Several parts";
                else
                    t = "Full parts";
                
                BodyTreatment bt = new BodyTreatment(num,name,m1,d,t);
                pay = pay + bt.computePayment();
            }
            System.out.println("Total : RM" + pay);
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me on how to solve this, I would be grateful enough. I failed to find any solutions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may happen due to wrong configuration, follow these steps:

1. Right Click on your project folder, Choose Build Path > Configure Build Path.
   [image]
2. Select “JRE System Library” and select Edit from the right side bar.
   [image]
3. Choose the version of JDK you have installed.
   [image]
4. Click on finish and refresh the project.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, click on the check mark on the left side of the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Comment: I used the latest version of eclipse which is JavaSE14 but still can't solve the problem...I already installed it's JDK.

Comment: Okay, Go to Window -> Preferences, and within that, Java -> Installed JREs and check if the JDK you've installed is listed.

Comment: it only display default jdk. I guess...I have to re-install the eclipse. Maybe something I missed up while installed it before.

Comment: No need to reinstall Eclipse, just click on Add -> select 'Standard VM' in 'Installed JRE types:' -> Next -> Click on Directory and browse to the JDK folder and set it as 'JRE home' -> Click on 'Finish'. You can now select this newly added JDK for the project build path.

Answer (score 0):

A whole code is not written, so i could not reproduce your problem.
But i think you shoud instanciate a parent component which might be JFrame or something before you use this method.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.lang.Object-

It says "The dialog uses the default frame,". Where is your default frame?